# Mantle of Inspiration with a mounted player

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat

If a bard applies Mantle of Inspiration to a mounted player with a controlled mount but not the mount itself, would they still get the reaction move?  I had ruled that they would, but it added a bit of RAW vs RAI conversation that we talked about and haven't seen any resolution in our searches.

EDIT:

Then the inverse, where the mount was granted but not the rider, would keep the controlled mount in the location since the rider doesn't cue the mount? Or would that be up to a reaction, if still available, for the mounted combatant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The feature only effects the target

The Bard feature [Mantle of Inspiration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#MantleofInspiration-649) says:

> ...choose a number of creatures you can see and that can see you within 60 feet of you, up to a number equal to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one). Each of them gains 5 temporary hit points. **When a creature gains these temporary hit points**, it can immediately use its reaction to move up to its speed, without provoking opportunity attacks.

Since the mount was not targeted, the mount does not gain the feature to move. The target can use half of the movement granted to dismount and move for the other half if they wish.

Additionally, even if the mount was a Find Steed/Find Greater Steed, both spells use similar language:

> While mounted on [the steed], you can make any **spell** you cast that targets only you also target the mount.

This only works for spells, and only if cast by the rider. Since Mantle of Inspiration is not a spell, this does not come into play.

#### Inversely...

If the feature targeted the mount and not the rider, nothing prevents it from using a reaction. However it depends on the type of mount. Per the [mounted combat rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ControllingaMount):

> While you’re mounted, you have two options. **You can either control the mount or allow it to act independently.** Intelligent creatures, such as dragons, act independently.
>
> You can control a mount only if it has been trained to accept a rider. Domesticated horses, donkeys, and similar creatures are assumed to have such training. The initiative of a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. **It moves as you direct it**, and it has only three action options: Dash, Disengage, and Dodge. A controlled mount can move and act even on the turn that you mount it.
>
> An independent mount retains its place in the initiative order. Bearing a rider puts no restrictions on the actions the mount can take, and **it moves and acts as it wishes**. It might flee from combat, rush to attack and devour a badly injured foe, or otherwise act against your wishes.
>
> In either case, if the mount provokes an opportunity attack while you’re on it, the attacker can target you or the mount.

A "controlled" mount will only move when the rider says move. Since the rider (unless otherwise prearranged by Readying an Action) cannot take a reaction to use the mount's reaction, the mount will stand still (or whatever the mount was doing for its turn). And since you did not direct it to move, nothing will happen.

But an "independent" mount can do as it pleases and can take advantage of being able to move as a reaction. And due to the feature, it does not provoke an Opportunity Attack for itself nor its rider.

Comment: I would suggest that this is somewhere we might consider that the technically correct answer isn't the most fun answer.

Answer (score 4):

### The rider can move, the mount cannot

The rider is the one affected so they could move by dismounting or by moving around on the mount if the mount is really big.

The mount still has its own movement and reactions but since it wasn’t a target, it doesn’t get to move.

Comment: Then the inverse, where the mount was granted but not the rider, would keep the controlled mount in the location since the rider doesn't cue the mount?  Or would that be up to a reaction, if still available, for the mounted combatant?

Comment: @JJMar You should update your question if you're looking for both cases.

Comment: @NautArch I assumed this would be a continuation of dialogue from the initial question through this potential answer's stance.  I'll update the question, still, as it's my first post.